# Is Atom suitable for general purpose C-code generation?

Tags: haskell, embedded, code-generation

Can you use [Atom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/atom) for programming C in Haskell? Would that be possible and would that make sense?

Comment: You certainly *could*, but depending on what sort of code you wanted to generate, I'm not sure how much sense it would make to do so. Could you expand on what your use case is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atom is targeted towards a very particular domain, "hard realtime embedded software", to quote the Atom blurb. If the problem you want to solve fall in that domain then you should definitely give Atom a go. But most likely your problem is quite a bit different and then you're probably much better off with [language-c](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c).

The abstractions that Atom provides aren't that C like anyway, so it's not always obvious what kind of C code Atom will generate.

Good luck!

Comment: I've been trying to use language-c for one of my projects but haven't had much luck with its documentation. Do you know of any good sources of documentation or good examples?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I agree it could use some good examples. I've just been going off the documentation myself but it's slow going.